# FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) returns null

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am using Spring, Hibernate and JSF.

In order to get a bean from application context I write:

```
public static Object findBean(String name) {
  return FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean(name);
 }
```

However, the `FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())` returns null, so calling `getBean()` on it throws `NullPointerException`

Do I need to define anything anywhere?

**EDITED**

I need to get the bean from application context and not jsf bean

Comment: What reference exactly is `null`? Those are static methods, they can impossibly throw NPE. Don't you mean that `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` returned `null` and that the NPE is actually been thrown inside `getWebApplicationContext()` method?

Comment: FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) returns null. The FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is not null!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null` if your are not within a request that is handled by the `FacesServlet`. Make sure you are handling a request passed through that servlet.

**Update:** If the faces context is not null, the reason why the application context may be null is that there is no servlet context attribute named `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT`. This means spring is not initialized properly. Make sure you have either the spring `ContextLoaderListener` mapped in `web.xml`, or the `DispatcherServlet`

Comment: See my comment to BalusC - FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is not null! I get com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl from it.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the ContextLoaderListener

Comment: @Odelya nice. Btw, an accepted answer with 0 upvotes seems kind of strange :)

Comment: @BalusC thanks. Btw, how did you add that less-than-15chrs comment? :)