# Wildfly 9.0.1.Final: EAR deployment failed

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly, ear

I am trying to deploy my struts based web application on Wildfly 9.0.1.Final.

I am deploying as an .ear file that contains .war/.jar(EJB) files.

But it gives me an error during deployment.

Error Stacktrace:

```
Failed to define class AuditMDB in Module "deployment.webapp.ear.EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link AuditMDB (Module "deployment.webapp.ear.EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.handleSessionBean(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.deploy(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.MessageListener from [Module "deployment.webapp.ear.EJB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 23 more
```

Please help

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins please help

Comment: Have you tried starting with `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`? I don't think JMS is added in the default standalone.xml configuration.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I tried starting with standalone-full.xml and now I am getting errors regarding "Unable to create initial lookups.: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/WEBFDMS". and my dbLoopup string is java:jboss/datasources/WEBFDMS. Also I wanted to know that do I need to start server always as you mentioned above or it is just a one time activity. I mean to say next time onwards can I start it just like $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh

Comment: For the datasource issue you need to define it like the answer states below. To not have to pass `-c standalone-full.xml` you need to add the JMS configurations to `standalone.xml` which is the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your datasource is defined. In your standalone-full.xml you need to include the definition, something like:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:datasources/WEBFDMS" pool-name="WEBFDMS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

"java:datasources/WEBFDMS" might have to be "java:jboss/datasources/WEBFDMS"

Of course, this datasource definition will simply create an in-memory datasource. In order to connect to a running database (mysql, oracle, etc) you will have to configure it differently.

Comment: How do I connect to a running database. And what about $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml ?

Comment: -c standalone-full.xml just says to load that as your config file.  but that file needs to be configured for your application. I'm afraid this isn't the right forum for a wildfly step by step, start by reading the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration

Comment: Ok. I;ll go through this